# "broken packages" error when installing Shutter from linuxuprising PPA on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutter

04 I wanted to re-install Shutter.

I followed the instructions found at https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/shutter-removed-from-ubuntu-1810-and.html (which also claims to work for 20.04)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install shutter
```

However Shutter still will not install:

```
 ~  sudo apt install shutter

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 shutter : Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas how I can get it installed?

**EDIT**:

```
sudo apt-cache policy shutter
shutter:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.94.3-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1
  Version table:
     0.94.3-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     0.94-1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Trying then to install `libgnome2-perl` :

```
libgnome2-perl : Depends: libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to install this:

```
libgnomeui-0 : Depends: libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.20.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and finally this

```
libgnome-keyring0 : Depends: libgnome-keyring-common (= 3.12.0-1build1~0ppa1~focal) but 3.12.0-1build1 is to be installed
```

Comment: The package `libgnome2-perl` conflicts with something. Try to install it first.

Comment: Not sure the comment section is the best place for code output. Does it look readable?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: idias: Yes that worked actually. Thanks! `sudo apt-get install -f "libgnome-keyring-common=3.12.0-1build1~0ppa1~focal"`  After which I could install `shutter`

Answer (score 2):

Your output of `sudo apt-cache policy shutter` shows that there is already a version of shutter installed (`/var/lib/dpkg/status` is what's actually installed or partially installed), so there is/was probably an update problem due to broken dependencies.

In such cases, I try to remove the problematic package first and then reinstall, first by doing `apt-get remove shutter`, and then by doing `dpkg -P shutter`, maybe with `--force-depends`, followed by `apt-get -f install`. Watch carefully what the last command does, because it tends to remove other packages which were also part of the problem - and sometimes more.

On my system, just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and no shutter installed anymore, the following three lines were enough for reinstalling shutter (it's possible that something was fixed meanwhile..):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```